# Struggling with Host Key and Grab Keyboard

Tags: remmina

I am using Remmina to connect via an ssh tunnel (Raspberry Pi) from my local Ubuntu 20.04 to a remote Ubuntu 20.04. It all works beautifully but I cannot get a single meta key to work. I have default settings for Host Key and Grab Keyboard (= Control_R). But if I press the right control key and any other meta key, like the super key (Windows key), F12, or combinations (like Ctrl+Alt+T) it never "catches" the input. The action is always executed on my client side Ubuntu. Is there something I am missing here?

I looked around *the internet* a bit and couldn't find anyone else with this problem. Some older versions of Ubuntu (or maybe just 18.04?) used Wayland and it seemed to cause a similar issue but as far as I understand, both my Ubuntu 20.04s use Xorg as the X server and therefor these solutions don't apply. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. The weird thing is that it was working flawlessly, and suddenly a week or so ago it started passing special keys to the host *always*. Haven't found a solution yes, so reporting a bug on remmina's gitlab might be the way to go: https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina